# Python 3.x Downloading images from image-net code

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib2, urllib3

I am using the following code (from Sentdex's OPENCV haar cascade training tutorial):

```
import urllib.request
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

def store_raw_images():
    neg_images_link = 'http://www.image-net.org/api/text/imagenet.synset.geturls?wnid=n00017222'   
    neg_image_urls = urllib.request.urlopen(neg_images_link).read().decode()
    pic_num = 1

    if not os.path.exists('neg'):
        os.makedirs('neg')

    for i in neg_image_urls.split('\n'):
        try:
            print(i)
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(i, "neg/"+str(pic_num)+".jpg")
            img = cv2.imread("neg/"+str(pic_num)+".jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            # should be larger than samples / pos pic (so we can place our image on it)
            resized_image = cv2.resize(img, (100, 100))
            cv2.imwrite("neg/"+str(pic_num)+".jpg",resized_image)
            pic_num += 1

        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
```

To download a bunch of images from IMAGENET so that I can train the Haar classifier. It basically should go to the link (which I had to change as it was broken) and download every picture from that link in order.

It doesn't run and doesn't give me an error (library-related errors on an ubuntu server and it tries installing different versions of Python on Windows 10).
I believe that I have the correct libraries on my windows - here's my current pip freeze output

```
numpy==1.18.1
opencv-python==4.2.0.32
urllib3==1.25.8
```

Comment: How is this function called? Is there another script that calls it or do you just run this script? If the latter you'll need to add something the likes of `if __name__ = __main__: store_raw_images()`.

Comment: @Jir I tried doing what Sentdex did in his tutorial which is run this script directly (I tried doing so from python shell, Cygwin, Ubuntu terminal (server) and power shell (usually with “python download-image-by-link.py”. 

Also since I’m new to Python (I’m just using it for my Capstone) I don’t really know where I should put the code that you suggested (which line in my code).